# What is the use of the 0.1Ohm Sense Resistor in Battery Charger

Tags: batteries, resistors, charging

In the below circuit, can someone please point out the use of the 100m Ohm resistor?

- Can i replace it with a 0Ohm Resistor?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of the 0.1-Ohm resistor is to provide a measurable voltage that corresponds to the current being supplied to the battery.  Note that pin 1 is labeled SENSE.  The fast charge current is determined by the value of that resistor, so replacing it with a 0-Ohm resistor will probably cause some very bad things to happen to your battery, the charging circuit, or both.

Comment: that's normally spelt 'Very Bad Things' !

Comment: @user44635 - While on the subject of spelling you should know that "spelt" is a grain being a type of wheat.

Comment: Well i did replace it with a 0R, and the Battery is just not charging. 

So let me  replace it with a 0.1R and see the results.

Comment: Then the controller must have detected the (apparent) absence of charging current, decided the cell must be dead, and switched off to prevent the Very Bad Things.

Comment: From the datasheet it doesn't look like this controller makes any very sophisticated decisions about dead cells.  I'm guessing what would happen is that it would output its maximum current in trying to get 110mV across that resistor, and this would bring the cell voltage up to the charge termination threshold and it would shut down.  So I guess my dire predictions were a little too pessimistic.